# Resubmitting form data with Flask and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, flask, frontend

I'm developing a dice app with Flask, (https://astrodados.herokuapp.com/juego) and I want to reroll the dice with the same form data (like a number of dice) without refreshing the page. To do so, I'm using Jquery and Ajax. I don't understand why, but I can't get the data, so I get the error "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'".
When I submit the form in juego.html, it sends me to resjuego.html and everything goes OK. But when I click on the reroll button ('#re_tirada') in resjuego.html, Jinja shows me the error. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I have seen tutorials and tried a lot of different ways of coding this, but I can't get the data.

I'm sending the form data with Ajax in juego.html:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            data : {
                signo : $('#signoInput').val(),
                pool : $('#poolInput').val(),
                magnitud : $('#magnitudInput').val() 
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/back_retirada'
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
...
<form action=" {{(url_for('resjuego'))}}", method="post">
<div class='text-center'>
  <div class="form.row">
    <div class="col">
    <p class = "instrucciones">Ingresa tu ascendente: </p>
        <div id='signo'>
      {{ form.signo (class_="form-control form-control-lg")}}
  </div>
      <p class = "instrucciones">Elige la cantidad de dados:</p>
      <div id='pool'>
      {{form.pool (class_="form-control form-control-lg")}}
      </div>
      <p class = "instrucciones">
      Elige la magnitud de tu acción: </p>
      <div id='magnitud'>
      {{form.magnitud (class_="form-control form-control-lg")}}
      </p>
  </div>
      </div>
    <button type="submit">¡Tira los dados!</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

this is the view where i'm receiving the data, in routes.py:

```py
@app.route('/back_retirada', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def back_retirada():    
    signo = request.form['signo']
    pool =  request.form['pool']
    magnitud = request.form['magnitud']
    
    return jsonify ({'signo' : signo, 'pool': pool, 'magnitud': magnitud})
```

this is the view of /resjuego:

```py
@app.route('/resjuego', methods=['GET','POST'])
def resjuego():
    form = CumuloForm()
    signo=request.form.get('signo')
    pool=request.form.get('pool', type = int)
    magnitud=request.form.get('magnitud', type = int)
    x = pool
    m = magnitud
    i=0
    roll=Dado.signar(x)
    res=roll
    y=rnd.randint(1,6)
    entropia=Dado.signar(y)
    thislist=[]
    thislist2=[]
    for i in range(x):
        thislist.append(Aspecto.aspectario(signo, res[0+i]))
        zumbi = thislist
    for i in range(y):
        thislist2.append(Aspecto.aspectario(signo, entropia[0+i]))
        zumbi2 = thislist2
    totalasp=zumbi+zumbi2
    conj = 2*(zumbi.count("conjunción"))
    semsex = 0*(zumbi.count("semisextil"))
    sext = 1*(zumbi.count("sextil"))
    cuad = -1*(zumbi.count("cuadratura"))
    trig = 1*(zumbi.count("trígono"))
    quinc = 0*(zumbi.count("quincuncio"))
    opos = -2*(zumbi.count("oposición"))

    conj2 = 2*(zumbi2.count("conjunción"))
    semsex2 = 0*(zumbi2.count("semisextil"))
    sext2 = 1*(zumbi2.count("sextil"))
    cuad2 = -1*(zumbi2.count("cuadratura"))
    trig2 = 1*(zumbi2.count("trígono"))
    quinc2 = 0*(zumbi2.count("quincuncio"))
    opos2 = -2*(zumbi2.count("oposición"))

    éxitos = conj + semsex + sext + cuad + trig + quinc + opos
    éxitosent= conj2 + semsex2 + sext2 + cuad2 + trig2 + quinc2 + opos2
    if éxitos + m <=0:
        rest="fallo"
    if éxitos >=0:
        rest="éxito"
    if éxitos <=0 and éxitos + m >=0:
        rest="adverso"
    des_exitos = descriptorc(rest)

    T1 = struli(zumbi)
    T2 = struli(zumbi2)
    res=struli(res)
    entropia=struli(entropia)

    return render_template('resjuego.html', title='Caosmos', lanzarcum=res, signo = signo, entropia=entropia, aspecto=T1, aspecto2=T2, éxitos=éxitos, éxitosent = éxitosent, des_exitos=des_exitos)
```

and this is the jquery code to get this data, in resjuego.html:

```js
        <script type=text/javascript>
            $(function() {
                $("#re_tirada").click(function() {$.getJSON(
                    '/back_retirada')
                    }) })
                </script>
...

<div class='text-center'>
    <form>
        <span href=# id=re_tirada><button>¡Lanza otra vez!</button> </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that you use the function `int()` but pass a value that is None. Unfortunately, this is not the case in the part of the code that you published. Could it be that you ask for a form value and want to convert it into an integer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do. I get the "pool" value from the form (a number in string) and then I convert it to integer. It works when I submit the data the first time, but it doesn't work when I try to reroll.

Comment: As an explanation, the following. AJAX is a way to transfer data in the background without reloading and rendering the entire page. You can also achieve your goal using a standard form. The form object is empty on the server side when you send a GET request, as you do, for example, with getJSON. So you should either use the request object or wtforms to differentiate between GET and POST requests if both methods are permitted for the end point. Wtforms offers you the additional advantage of validating the entry.

Comment: I understand your intention, but your attempt is overwhelming. Many different techniques are used within your code. You should reduce yourself to a minimum in order to reach your goal step by step. I deleted my answer as it is no longer helpful. Please don't give up, you will achieve your goal. I'm sorry I couldn't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need to resubmit the form at all.
In this example, the form data is transmitted once and saved in the session cookie. From then on, these will be sent to the server every time a transmission takes place.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import redirect, render_template, request, session, jsonify, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, NumberRange
import random 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'your secret here'

class ClusterForm(FlaskForm):
    sign = StringField(
        'Sign',
        validators=[DataRequired()],
        description='Enter your ascendant.'
    )
    pool = IntegerField(
        'Pool',
        validators=[NumberRange(min=1, max=6)],
        description='Choose the number of dice.'
    )
    magnitude = IntegerField(
        'Magnitude',
        validators=[NumberRange(min=1)],
        description='Choose the magnitude of your action.'
    )

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/game', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def game():
    form = ClusterForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for k in ('sign', 'pool', 'magnitude'):
            session[k] = form[k].data
        return redirect(url_for('play'))
    return render_template('game.html', **locals())

@app.route('/play')
def play():
    if not all(k in session for k in ('sign', 'pool', 'magnitude')):
        return redirect(url_for('game'))
    return render_template('play.html')

@app.route('/turn')
def turn():
    sign = session.get('sign')
    pool = session.get('pool', 1)
    magnitude = session.get('magnitude', 1)

    print(sign, pool, magnitude)

    # Your calculation here!
    # A simplified example based on several dice rolls.
    throws = sum(random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(pool))
    result = ('misfortune', 'fortune')[throws >= 0.56*6*pool]

    return jsonify(prognosis=result)
```

Here is the template called "game.html".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Game</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Game</h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('game') }}" method="post">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      <div>
        {{ form.sign.label }}
        {{ form.sign(class_='form-control' + ('', ' is-invalid')[form.sign.errors | count > 0]) }}
        {% if form.sign.errors: %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ form.sign.errors[0] }}
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">
        {{ form.sign.description }}
        </small>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ form.pool.label }}
        {{ form.pool(class_='form-control' + ('', ' is-invalid')[form.pool.errors | count  > 0]) }}
        {% if form.pool.errors: %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ form.pool.errors[0] }}
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">
        {{ form.pool.description }}
        </small>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ form.magnitude.label }}
        {{ form.magnitude(class_='form-control' + ('', ' is-invalid')[form.magnitude.errors | count  > 0]) }}
        {% if form.magnitude.errors: %}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ form.magnitude.errors[0] }}
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">
        {{ form.magnitude.description }}
        </small>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the template called "play.html".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Play</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Sign</th>
        <td>{{ session['sign'] }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Pool</th>
        <td>{{ session['pool'] }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Magnitude</th>
        <td>{{ session['magnitude'] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="main">
      <h2 id="prognosis">Loading</h2>
      <button id="roll">Roll</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      function roll() {
        $('#prognosis').html("Loading");
        $.getJSON('/turn')
          .done(data => {
            console.log(data);
            $('#prognosis').html(data.prognosis);
          });
      }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#roll').click(roll);
        roll();
      });
    })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't knew about that type converter, it's useful, but the error have just changed the line: pool keeps being a Nonetype, because it has no content.

Comment: Sorry for the commas (too much JS). 
I edited the code to show more of the process, and to add the GET method to the view. I have tried to call the ajax method like you show, but it keeps not working. the serialize method doesn't work because I need these data not to be printed, but to be considered as variables for the roll. How should I do that?

Comment: @ejeytijera I've dealt with your question again and updated my answer. I hope my example meets your requirements and helps you achieve your goal. If you have any questions, please leave me a comment.

Comment: thanks! I have tried your code, but sadly I didn't get anything: now, not even the first roll is possible. I didn't have used until now the session object of flask; I read that it was insecure, but it's irrelevant if the data is for dice rolls. I won't give up, because every way of seeking a solution has been a new thing learned.  The error is the same: it doesn't recognize the value of "pool" because it doesn't exists (is a NoneType). I will rearrange my code to make it more readable, when I have the time. I realize that it's very important when asking for help.

Comment: @ejeytijera The session is not generally insecure. As you already mentioned, it depends on what you store in it, how easy it is to guess the secret key of the application and so on. You can take advantage of it. The code runs flawlessly for me, but I have changed it slightly. If the code does not work after all, please tell me what you will get as feedback within the terminal and in the webdeveloper console.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have edited my code, and your recommendation works. I had to adapt a lot of things, because my calculations were a little complex. Here you can see the results: https://astrodados.herokuapp.com/juego . I think my main problem was that I wanted to jsonify the form values, but finally the other values were the jsonified ones (i had all the calculation in the view "resjuego", and not in the back view).